# React HOC—add Event Listeners to wrapped Component

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to create an HOC which makes a regular functional component »Touchable«.

So I have that an HOC like that:

```
const Touchable = (Component, handler) => {
  const T = ({props, children}) => {
    const Instance = React.createElement(
      Component, 
      {
        ...props,
        onTouchStart: (e) => handler.touchStart(e),
        /*more listeners*/
      }, children);
  }

  return T;
}
```

Another Component like so:

```
const Button = ({props, children}) => <div>…</div>;

export default Touchable(Button, {touchStart: () => {}});
```

Using this like so:

```
<Button>Hallo</Button>
```

results in (react developer Panel):

```
<Button onTouchStart={…}>
  <div>…</div>
</Button>
```

But what I really would like to have is:

```
<Button>
  <div onTouchStart={…}>…</div>
</Button>
```

I have tried to clone the Instance, but somehow I have no luck. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just return the `Component` without `React.createElement` part?

Something like:

```js
const TouchableHOC = (Component, handler) =>
  (props) =>
    <Component
      {...props}
      onClick={(event) => handler.touchStart(event)}
    />

const YourComponent = ({ children, onClick }) =>
  <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>


const EnhancedComponent = TouchableHOC(
  YourComponent,
  { touchStart: () => console.log('touchStart') }
)

const WithoutRest = TouchableHOC(
  'button',
  { touchStart: () => console.log('touchStart') }
)

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <EnhancedComponent>
      Click-me
    </EnhancedComponent>
    <WithoutRest>
      No props at all
    </WithoutRest>
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Right now I have set it up similary, but I would love to find a way to get rid of the `{...rest}` in the wrapped component. I guess there is no way to make that happen?

Comment: @philipp I don't think so. Unless you know in advance which props you need to pass through.

Comment: well yes, in that case: `onTouch[Start|Move|End]`

Comment: So in this case you can get rid of `rest` and destruct injected props from your HOC.

Comment: Of course ;) But I would love to have nothing to write at all ;)

Comment: I think you can send `'Button'` (as string) instead though.

Comment: Please check my answer, maybe it might help you :)

Comment: The way shown seams to show the closest possible solutions, thanks for that!

Comment: Assuming that `TouchableHOC` is in a separate file. So, how to implement the `touchStart()` here instead of `EnhancedComponent`?

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues I'm not sure I'm following you here. `TouchableHOC` can be a separate file regardless.

Comment: The TouchableHOC is in a separate file; So, I'm trying to implement the `handleClick` in this file and show the props on App component.

Comment: I think your example is a bit different than the question asked here in SO. `TouchableHOC` is a higher-order component whereas in your example you are using render props. Not sure how can they fit together.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `React.cloneElement` to clone the `children` and attach custom props to them

```
const Touchable = (Component, handler) => {
  const T = ({props, children}) => {
    const Instance = React.createElement(
      Component, 
      props,
      React.cloneElement(children, {
           onTouchStart: (e) => handler.touchStart(e),
           /*more listeners*/
      });
    )
  }

  return T;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. This way the the »listeners« are actually added to the children of the component like so: `<div class="wrapped-component"><div class="child" onTouchStart="…"></div></div>`. So that wont work if there are no children given…

Comment: You do want to attach listener to children only right or is there something else